# How to get more authenticated to github-cli?

Tags: authentication, github, github-cli

I am authenticated to github cli via token

```sh
gh auth status -h lalala.com
#=>
lalala.com
  ✓ Logged in to lalala.com as lolofon (~/.config/gh/hosts.yml)
  ✓ Git operations for lalala.com configured to use https protocol.
```

but, immediately executed afterwards:

```sh
gh pr list --repo lala/portal
#=>
HTTP 401: This endpoint requires you to be authenticated. (https://api.github.com/graphql)
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently its a bug :-(
You can workaround it very easily by setting an env var like this:

> `set GH_HOST=lalala.com`

See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/1745#issuecomment-694377743) for details

Answer (score 0):

See also [PR 7449](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/7449) which is now (May 2023) part of [`gh` v2.30.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.30.0):

> As an avid `github.com` Actions users, I spent several hours debugging 401 authentication failures that targeted a Github Enterprise Server (GHES) appliance.
>
> I 100% saw the note that "if I was setting `GH_ENTERPRISE_TOKEN` then I should set `GH_HOST`". When I saw the auth failure for `api.github.com` I immediately knew I needed to set `GH_HOST`.
>
> I had no idea that `GH_TOKEN` and `GITHUB_TOKEN` [are disregarded](https://github.com/cli/go-gh/blob/ccb69a6ec9775c1d6efe8f0ab4ca404439e543a7/pkg/auth/auth.go#L64-L70) if `GH_HOST` [is not equal to either](https://github.com/cli/go-gh/blob/ccb69a6ec9775c1d6efe8f0ab4ca404439e543a7/pkg/auth/auth.go#L151-L153) `github` or `localhost`.